# Select all comments from friends - Mysql Query

Tags: mysql, select, comments

I have a `comments` and `friends` table in mySQL database.

The `comments` table contains the following columns:

```
member_id, comment_id, comment, video_id
```

The `friends` table contains the following columbs:

```
member_id, member_id_friend
```

Is there a query to select all comments from your friends in a specific video id?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a table like friends, it's called a "join table".  These are used for many-to-many relationships between items.  The way your particular schema is set up, the friends table is a join table implementing the many-to-many relationship between members and other members (their friends), so some would call it a "self-join table".

Tables like this are called join tables because the way to get relevant data from them is to "join" them to other tables.  This is because they don't, themselves, contain any real data to speak of.

If you're trying to get the collection associated with an individual in a many-to-many relationship, you typically use an "inner join", which restricts results from one table to records which have a match in the join table.  In this case, it'd look like:

```
select * from comments c
inner join friends f on c.member_id = f.member_id
where f.member_id_friend = [current user ID]
  and c.video_id = [desired video ID]
```

Let us know how that works for you.

Comment: Interesting, I'd never heard them called "join table"s before, but apparently [they have many names](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table).

Comment: Guess I'm showing a bit of a Java bias - most Java persistence frameworks call them join tables.

Comment: Wow thank you very much for your comment! I dont get any errors at all, just 0 results which is weird because I have someone as friend who has posted a comment. :(

Comment: Maybe I interpreted the column meanings backward?  In which case it'd be 'inner join friends f on c.member_id = f.member_id_friend' and 'where f.member_id = [current user ID]'.  Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

```
select comment 
from comments 
join friends (on comments.member_id = friends.member_id) 
where member_id_friend = <id number> & video_id = <video id>;
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I get the following error:
mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in..

But does this select the comments from my friends, from my id?

Comment: It'll grab all the values in the comment column; based off your video_id, i missed the condition for your friend_id.

Comment: You missed a requirement - all comments from _your_ friends.  So you'll need to add the ID of the "you" (the member to whose friends you're trying to restrict the results)